# Do we want to unpin the accepted answer from the top?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[Stack Overflow is not pinning the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers) to the top any longer.

What would we like for our site?

- Keep things as they are, as the right answer is not changing in aviation as it does for code.
- or change to the new method, because the best answers are not always the accepted ones?

Comment: This has been added to the Community Team's backlog and we'll update you once someone picks it up and evaluates your request.

Comment: Hey! I've updated the site settings. Now the accepted answer is unpinned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would propose to change to the new method:

**Unpin the accepted answer and show the top voted answer first.**

---

*I added my reasoning below. If you agree with changing to the new method, feel free to add your reasoning below. If you disagree, please post another answer so people can vote on it.*

---

The whole idea of accepting answers does not really make sense on Aviation.SE. For a programming site, the idea is this:

1. You have a **problem** and post a question on StackOverflow.
2. Multiple users post their **solutions** to the problem as answers.
3. Users **vote** on how useful each of these solutions are.
4. You end up using one of their proposed solutions in your code and **accept** that answer.

Most questions on Aviation.SE do not follow this principle since there is no specific problem to be solved. We recently modified our [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) help center page because of this (see [Proposed edit to "Don't ask" help page](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4166/proposed-edit-to-dont-ask-help-page)).

Without a specific problem, there is no solution that was implemented. This leaves users with choosing the *best* answer as the accepted one, which often depends on personal preference.

---

The tick has always meant most helpful to OP, not correct/approved/best, so the new system in my opinion removes this ambiguity.

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally. ([Help Center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer))

Comment: I upvoted this answer (and TomMcW's), but with some hesitation.  I think it's a worthwhile experiment, but if it goes awry, there needs to be an ***abort*** lever for the pilots (mods/CMs/sysadmins in this case) to pull.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I feel like this is going somewhat awry. I have yet to come across a situation where I felt glad the accepted answer wasn't pinned, but in the short time of this experiment I've come across several where I've seen top-voted answers crowd out the accepted answer because the accepted answer happened after the question cooled off.

Comment: @KennSebesta Yes, that describes the downside very well. Have you experienced that on this SE community?  If so, do you have a couple good examples you can post?  I would like to take a look.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I'll keep an eye open. The one I can point to right now, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/93280/are-there-any-many-us-airports-with-instrument-approaches-still-without-rnav-a, isn't the best example because it's early on. It just got me thinking because I don't know if I should downvote the top voted answers in order to facilitate the canonically correct answer getting to the top. Especially because that question both has a canonically correct answer, but it also has a lot of great, thoughtful, enlightening anwers.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I can point to one which probably would have worked out badly, if the answer had happened after the SE change. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515729/how-to-abort-a-stash-pop/60444590#60444590, where the correct answer as of 2020 languished at the bottom of a wall of code for about a year, until the OP came back and gave it the nod. Now it's the top-voted *and* the correct answer, but if `git` changes again so that there's a new "best", it could be a long, long time before the right answer makes it high enough to catch anyone's attention.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the new method should be preferred. Sometimes the OP accepts an answer too quickly and better answers may come along.

Comment: Since it's the same choice as @Bianfable's answer, be sure to upvote it instead, and you can leave that answer as a comment. Will make it easier to wrap up the consensus :)

Comment: @ymb1 I turned my answer into community wiki so others can add their reasons for changing to the new method. That should simplify the voting...

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd prefer to **keep the existing accepted answer pinned behavior**.

The primary reason for this is that it's quite common for someone to post a superior answer after others have already attracted upvotes. Under the newly-proposed system where accepted answers aren't pinned, the new, better answer would often languish in obscurity beneath possibly several answers that were posted sooner and already had some upvotes.

This effect is especially strong when a good answer is posted more than a couple of days after the question was posted. The person who posted the question will get a notification when the new answer is posted - and possibly choose to change the accepted answer if they think it's better - but most others would never see it if there were already at least a few other answers with some upvotes, even if only a few. This is not helped by the fact that questions tend to get a lot more visibility soon after they are posted.

By moving the accepted answer to the top, the later answer is pulled out of obscurity at the bottom to a position where it's much more likely to be seen (and voted on) by others.

The worst that can happen with the current (accepted answer pinned) behavior is that one lower-voted answer appears above the others, while the remainder remain sorted by votes. Whereas the worst that can happen by unpinning is that the best answer is hidden under a pile of answers that aren't quite as helpful, but were posted earlier.

---

What I'd really like to see is an option to pin the accepted answer above *all answers that are older than it*, but, unfortunately, that's not one of our options here, so I think that maintaining the current behavior of accepted answers being pinned is the best of the two options presently available to us. Hopefully SE will come up with a better sorting algorithm that takes age of votes into account later on. Possibly they will come up with something better in [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/271431).

Comment: A month ago I voiced the [**same** primary concern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369580/392799) on the main meta, but the staff's response was encouraging (this is only the beginning of fixing things). Try this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/1462401/questions-with-accepted-answer-pinned-above-highest-scoring-answer) for Aviation, and I'm sure you'll find many examples where the lesser answer is pinned (and that's the main issue: pinning is subjective). The staff's response and that query helped me see the potential of the new system.

Comment: @ymb1 Yes, I also voiced that concern on SE or SO meta (I forget which) and did see that they are planning to eventually come up with something better. As for the SEDE query, I've seen similar query results of higher-voted answers below the accepted one cited as evidence for the change, but that by itself really isn't, as it could equally well be evidence of exactly the problem this answer is describing - vote bias towards earlier answers. I'm sure there are examples both ways, but, clicking through those results, I'm seeing several that were just that - better answers posted later.

Comment: Still, there are several that aren't better: the tick has always meant *most helpful to OP,* not correct/approved/best, so the new system IMO removes this ambiguity. Also possibly if Aviation doesn't join now, we might miss whatever they'll come up with to fix the other concerns. (BTW, -1 not mine :) )