# Has anyone come across posts in Aviation.SE where unpinning an answer was crucially helpful?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

The decision was made to unpin accepted answers, per [Do we want to unpin the accepted answer from the top?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/do-we-want-to-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top/4256#4256).
There was a [good argument for why](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/do-we-want-to-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top/4256#comment5494_4256) this was a worthwhile experiment, even if some of us had reservations.

It's been about [6 months since this was implemented](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/do-we-want-to-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top/4256#comment5542_4253), and that's probably enough time to see how things are shaking out. Get the temperature of the room so to speak.

*What examples have we seen where where unpinning the answer was crucially helpful?* As in, we would have fundamentally misunderstood/misconstrued/"mislearned" the concept asked in the question, if the accepted answer had still been the pinned answer.

---

Anecdotally, I've seen several instances to the contrary, where the right *accepted* answer was buried because it came too late to get upvotes while the question was hot. And I've not yet appreciated having the accepted answer not be on top. But perhaps that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @KennSebesta. The best answer might have been provided after some time, meaning it won't ever be the most popular answer. With the OP accepting an answer, meaning it answers the question they posed in the best possible way, that accepted answer would deserve more attention than when it is buried in the answer stack.

Answer (score -1):

> Anecdotally, I've seen several instances to the contrary, where the
> right answer was buried because it came too late to get upvotes while
> the question was hot. And I've not yet appreciated having the accepted
> answer not be on top. But perhaps that's just me

Agreed.  It's better if the "accepted" answer is not pinned to the top.

But am unable to provide specific "examples have we seen where where unpinning the answer was crucially helpful? As in, we would have fundamentally misunderstood/misconstrued/"mislearned" the concept asked in the question, if the accepted answer had still been the pinned answer.", as requested.  Perhaps because I don't pay much attention to what answer is pinned to the top anyway.  *Most* of the time the "accepted" answer is a good one, but I've seen plenty of cases where it is not.

.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying, and that you *disagree* (or at least *do not agree*). I updated my post to make it clear that the "right answer" refers is the one the OP accepted.